# Sign in as a different user Changing URL % as %25

Tags: 2013

In url having space %20,when i am clicking as Sign as different user it was changing to

%20 as %2520,so %is changing as %25,because of this i am unable to login as another user,can any one help on this issue.

Comment: How have you enabled "Sign in as different user"? By adding MenuItemTemplate in Welcome.ascx control template?

Comment: Yes,Please give me any solution

Comment: For some reason it re-encodes the url. Modifying the files in SharePoint root is not a good idea. You better try other ways to add "Sign in as differen user" functionality. [Link1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odabasi/archive/2013/08/16/missing-quot-sign-in-as-different-user-quot-option-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) , [Link2](http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/how-to-sign-in-as-a-different-user-in-sharepoint-2013/)